# trasparent modal dialogs with jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, modal-dialog

i'm trying to create a modal dialog with jquery mobile rc2.
This is my code:

```
<div id="info" data-role="page" data-fullscreen="true"> 
        <div data-role="content">
             Info
             <a data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" href="#dialog" >Dialog</a>
        </div>
</div>

<div id="dialog" data-role="page" data-fullscreen="true">
    <div data-role="content"> 
       <p>This is Page 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see there is no javascript code as jqm is supposed to handle this automatically.

The dialog looks beautiful but the background goes dark. I want to show just the dialog over my page normal background.
What am i supposed to do? Is it even possible? I didn't find any piece of documentationa about that, but it is a quite common problem i think...
Please help if you can!

Comment: I know this isn't what you want but maybe it will get you thinking of alternatives: http://jsfiddle.net/UWEWA/8/

Comment: Well, it seems to be a quite good solution even if select is not intended to be used like this i guess....
Even if i like your suggestion i'll wait if someone else can give a cleaner solution.
In the meantime, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, after looking deeper your solution does not work for me as i have a list of about 10 buttons. Every button must open a different dialog that the user can use. With the select/options solution when i click the dialog disappear so it's not good for me. Also, when i try to add more options to the select it behaves a little weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long exaustive deeper search i found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937405/can-i-fix-the-width-and-the-height-of-jquerymobile-dialog/7865324#comment9780296_7865324) that is similar to mine. It solves the problems even if it does not handle nested dialogs correctly.
Hope jQuery Mobile team will solve this before official release!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery ui to create a [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) that can be either modal or not.
I know this is not what you are searching for exactly but give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet might be to use the actionsheet plugin: https://github.com/hiroprotagonist/jquery.mobile.actionsheet#readme

I find it works fairly well and hopefully they'll role that into a future jquery mobile release.  Be careful about clicking on links in the darkened background.  I haven't figured out how to turn those off with this plugin.

Comment: Do you know if this plugin render correct data-theme attributes? Also, from the screenshot it seems to miss header which i need desperately