# How to make jQuery UI dialog box larger on iphones

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using the jQuery UI dialog. The sizing is fine on a regular desktop computer. But, when I view the dialog box on an iPhone, the box and accompanying text are so small that one must zoom in to read it. I don't want the box to overwhelm the screen on a regular desktop computer, but I do want the dialog to take up most of the screen space on an iPhone. I'm trying to figure out the best way to accomplish this.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
...

.dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Disclaimer',
        resizable: false,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        position: 'top+10%',
        buttons: {
...
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937405/can-i-fix-the-width-and-the-height-of-jquerymobile-dialog

Comment: Sunny, I'm not sure that the post to which you linked answers my question. I'm specifically asking about the dialog in jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, where the selector is the div contained by your dialog, maybe? You could do multiple ones for different widths, or use SASS to make the width dynamic.

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 320px){
  .selector{ width = 320;}
}
```